# Find all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $e^z = 1$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

We write $z=a+ib$. Now,

$$1 = e^z = e^{a+ib} = e^a e^{ib} = e^a(\cos b + i\sin b) = e^a\cos b + ie^a\sin b$$

We have
$$1 = e^a \cos b \\ 0 = e^a\sin b$$

Now, I don't understand why it has to be that $$1 = e^a\cos b = \color{red}{e^a (-1)^n}$$

Comment: $e^a\neq 0$ for any real value of $a$, so $0=e^a\sin b$ implies that $\sin b = 0$ which implies...  Now, that occurs only when $\cos b = 1$ or $-1$.  Since $e^a>0$ for all real $a$, that implies that $\cos b$ is not negative.  That implies $\cos b = 1$ which then implies that $e^a=1$.  What values of $a$ and $b$ satisfy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $e^a$ never equals $0$, it follows from $0=e^a \sin b$ that $\sin b=0$, hence $\cos b$ takes as values either $1$ or $-1$, hence this implies that $1=e^a\cos b=e^a(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Elimination You're welcome! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^a \neq 0$, we can divide both sides of the second equation, $0 = e^a \sin b$ by $e^a$, giving $$\sin b = 0 .$$ This has solution $$b = n \pi, \quad n \in \Bbb Z,$$ and substituting this in the remaining equation gives
$$1 = e^a \cos (n \pi) = e^a (-1)^n$$
as claimed.

Comment: Oh right. I have to get some sleep! many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful!